# Fire onmouseover only when mouse over is more than 3 seconds usnig jquery

Tags: jquery

I have some links like as shown below, here is a [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/3YBr8/) to it.

**What I want ?**

I want the jquery methods to be fired only when the mouse over is more than 3 seconds. I know I have to use `setTimeout` but I am not able to understand how to use it.

If anyone can help me by editing my [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/3YBr8/)

**HTML CODE**

```
<ul>
     <li>
          <a onmouseout="RemoveDetails(this)" onmouseover="GetSomeDetail('Sachin (actor)', this)" onclick="Suggestion('Sachin (actor)');" class="link">Sachin (actor)</a>
     </li>
     <li>
          <a onmouseout="RemoveDetails(this)" onmouseover="GetSomeDetail('Sachin Dev Burman', this)" onclick="Suggestion('Sachin Dev Burman');" class="link">Sachin Dev Burman</a>
     </li>
     <li>
          <a onmouseout="RemoveDetails(this)" onmouseover="GetSomeDetail('Sachin Pilot', this)" onclick="Suggestion('Sachin Pilot');" class="link">Sachin Pilot</a>
     </li>
     <li>
          <a onmouseout="RemoveDetails(this)" onmouseover="GetSomeDetail('Sachin Rana', this)" onclick="Suggestion('Sachin Rana');" class="link">Sachin Rana</a>
     </li>
     <li>
          <a onmouseout="RemoveDetails(this)" onmouseover="GetSomeDetail('Sachin Tendulkar', this)" onclick="Suggestion('Sachin Tendulkar');" class="link">Sachin Tendulkar</a>
     </li>
     <li>
          <a onmouseout="RemoveDetails(this)" onmouseover="GetSomeDetail('Sachin, Pas-de-Calais', this)" onclick="Suggestion('Sachin, Pas-de-Calais');" class="link">Sachin, Pas-de-Calais</a>
     </li>
</ul>
<hr/>
<p style="color:red;" id="moreInfo"></p>
```

**JQUERY CODE**

```
function GetSomeDetail(input, currentContext) {   
    $("#moreInfo").text(input);
}

function RemoveDetails(currentContext) {
    $("#moreInfo").text('Unloaded !');
}
```

Please help me out on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
var timeout;
    toExecute = function () {
        //
    };


$(XYZ).on({
    mouseover: function () {
        if(timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(toExecute, 3000);
    },
    mouseleave': function () {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
);
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/3YBr8/5/)'s the implementation on your fiddle.

Comment: as you see, I need to pass parameters generated from the link, how do i do that ?

Comment: Good answer - picked up the subtlety of cancelling the timeout if the mouse leaves the area before the timeout expires. Upvote!

Comment: could you edit the fiddle link please.... I tried this http://jsfiddle.net/3YBr8/1/ with your code, doesnt work as expected

Comment: I'm a little bit out of time right now. If you have any other question I'll only be able to answer it in a couple of hours from now.

Comment: @JOPLOmacedo no more questions, you already have made by day. God bless u !

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use [this plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html).

You can make this using `setTimeout()` but you may have a bit more problems than you think

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/3YBr8/2/

You can clean up the code a lot by setting events in script instead of in the HTML markup. You can put the text that you need in the script in a data attribute for each item.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a data-input="Sachin (actor)" class="link">Sachin (actor)</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a data-input="Sachin Dev Burman" class="link">Sachin Dev Burman</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a data-input="Sachin Pilot" class="link">Sachin Pilot</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a data-input="Sachin Rana" class="link">Sachin Rana</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a data-input="Sachin Tendulkar" class="link">Sachin Tendulkar</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a data-input="Sachin, Pas-de-Calais" onclick="Suggestion('Sachin, Pas-de-Calais');" class="link">Sachin, Pas-de-Calais</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<hr/>
<p style="color:red;" id="moreInfo"></p>
```

Start a timer when the user hovers an item. Use a variable to hold the handle for the timer, so that you can stop the timer if the mouse if removed before the time has passed.

```
function info(text) {
    $("#moreInfo").text(text);
}

function GetSomeDetail(input) {   
    info(input);
}

function RemoveDetails() {
    info('Unloaded !');
}

function Suggestion(input) {
    alert(input);
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    var timer = null;

    $('.link').mouseover(function(){
        if (timer != null) {
            RemoveDetails();
        }
        var input = $(this).data('input');
        timer = window.setTimeout(function(){
            timer = null;
            GetSomeDetail(input);
        }, 3000);
        info('timer started');
    }).mouseout(function(){
        if (timer != null) {
            window.clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = null;
            info('timer stopped');
        } else {
            RemoveDetails();
        }
    }).click(function(){
        Suggestion($(this).data('input'))
    });

});
```

I have added calls to show some information when the timer is started or stopped, those would of course not be there in the final result.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="link">Sachin (actor)</a></li>
    <li><a class="link">Sachin Dev Burman</a></li>
    <li><a class="link">Sachin Pilot</a></li>
    <li><a class="link">Sachin Rana</a></li>
    <li><a class="link">Sachin Tendulkar</a></li>
    <li><a class="link">Sachin, Pas-de-Calais</a></li>
</ul>
<hr/>
<p style="color:red;" id="moreInfo"></p>
```

js

```
var timer;

$(".link").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        var text = $(this).text();
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            $("#moreInfo").text(text);
        }, 1000); //set to one second now
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $("#moreInfo").text('Unloaded !');
    },
    click: function() {
        Suggestion($(this).text());
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3YBr8/3/)
​